# How do I collapse an empty div?

Tags: css

I have a div that I want to use for dynamic content. When the content that fills the div is non-existent, I don't want to see it. Right now, I can see about a 5px box. Even when I remove the padding, I can still see about 1px of the box. How do I remove the box when there is no content?

```
#test {
border:1px dashed red;
font-size:16px;
margin:20px 0 0 0;
width:332px;
background-color:#eee;
padding:5px 0 5px 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is a div . You have to do this with server-side programming language (or maybe javascript) . For example :

```
if(content()) // if there is any content
{
 echo "<div id=\"test\"></div>";
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: OK, Eray, that's what I was afraid of. I was going to do just that but I thought I'd ask first. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

You can do in CSS:

```
 div#test:empty {
       display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Please note this is a CSS 3 selector. Only works in IE9+

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_empty - check here for browser support. Basically any browser released since 2011 supports the  `css :empty` selector.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `padding`,`margin` and `border` (which you don't mention in your question) then the height will be 0px, and you will not see anything in the browser. Check the screenshot below and the `offsetHeight` value. [image]

For example you can create another div below `#test` and then add `display:none` for `#test`, you will see that the position of the second `div` doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

There's a jquery way of doing this as well, if you're interested. The [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector can hide things like so:

```
$('#test:empty').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the search box in the upper right corner?

[Hide empty div](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+empty+div) will point you to some same questions, that have been answered before.